# Coverity Scan Setup?

Tags: c++, c, code-analysis, coverity

Coverity offers a free scanning service for free and open source projects (http://scan.coverity.com). I'm trying to configure a project for a scan according to [Download Coverity Scan Self-Build](http://scan.coverity.com/download). From their web page:

> For each build:
>
> 1. cd to your build directory
> 2. optional: Run any build steps that you don't want to analyze – i.e. ./configure
> 3. cov-build --dir cov-int [BUILD CMD and ARGS]

I have three questions:

- Is `make` considered a build script for these purposes? Or is it part of [BUILD CMD and ARGS]
- Does their build slave include libraries such as Boost? We have an [undesired] dependency on the library
- What configuration does the scanning service want? Debug, Test, or Release?

Comment: This question appears to be off-topic because it is about using an online service, not about programming.

Comment: The topic is about using a software tool. I don't believe its different than a question on how to use `make` or `gcc`. Plus, the 'Coverity' tag was already present in SO, so others seem to be using the tool and asking questions about it, too.

Comment: Sorry this went closed for so long. For some reason, many users seem to have missed the memo that questions about development tools are well and on-topic for SO.

Comment: @jww: hi, I am wanna learn to do static code analysis using coverity. How to download the tool? is there any trial version of that? the download page is asking me to get associated with at least one project. I have sent some requests to the admin of the projects for access. If the admin accepts my request, will I be able to download the tool or is there any other way?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

> - Is make considered a build script for these purposes? Or is it part of [BUILD CMD and ARGS]

Yes! simply use `make` as `BUILD CMD`. Alternatively `ant`, `cmake`, whatever your build system is based on.

> - Does their build slave include libraries such as Boost? We have an [undesired] dependency on the library

You may configure this rule

> - What configuration does the scanning service want? Debug, Test, or Release?

Doesn't matter, you can scan any configuration you want.

Comment: Thanks g-makulik. Is there a preferred Linux platform? For example, does Ubuntu 12 work better than Fedora 17? Or does Red Hat work better than Fedora?

Comment: @noloader _'Is there a preferred Linux platform?'_ Not that I'm aware about. We've recently evaluated Coverity using their trial process at work, my platform there (and for the Jenkins build) is a Suse 12.2, but I really don't think, it should matter for the static analysis somehow (despite you'd like to have specific rules based on usage of particular OS specifi functions and APIs).