# How do I connect a Jenkins slave to a Git server with self signed certificate?

Tags: git, ssl, jenkins, certificate

When my Jenkins (v1.563) slave tries to clone a Git repository via HTTPS, it fails due to the Git server's self signed certificate. The Git plugin is at version 2.2.1 and the Git client plugin at 1.9.0. I get the following error:

```
FATAL: Failed to fetch from https://myserver/repo.git
hudson.plugins.git.GitException: Failed to fetch from https://myserver/repo.git
    at hudson.plugins.git.GitSCM.fetchFrom(GitSCM.java:623)
    at hudson.plugins.git.GitSCM.retrieveChanges(GitSCM.java:855)
    at hudson.plugins.git.GitSCM.checkout(GitSCM.java:880)
    at hudson.model.AbstractProject.checkout(AbstractProject.java:1251)
    at hudson.model.AbstractBuild$AbstractBuildExecution.defaultCheckout(AbstractBuild.java:604)
    at jenkins.scm.SCMCheckoutStrategy.checkout(SCMCheckoutStrategy.java:86)
    at hudson.model.AbstractBuild$AbstractBuildExecution.run(AbstractBuild.java:513)
    at hudson.model.Run.execute(Run.java:1706)
    at hudson.model.FreeStyleBuild.run(FreeStyleBuild.java:43)
    at hudson.model.ResourceController.execute(ResourceController.java:88)
    at hudson.model.Executor.run(Executor.java:231)
Caused by: hudson.plugins.git.GitException: sun.security.validator.ValidatorException: PKIX path building failed: sun.security.provider.certpath.SunCertPathBuilderException: unable to find valid certification path to requested target
    at org.jenkinsci.plugins.gitclient.CliGitAPIImpl.checkCredentials(CliGitAPIImpl.java:1964)
    at org.jenkinsci.plugins.gitclient.CliGitAPIImpl.launchCommandWithCredentials(CliGitAPIImpl.java:1143)
    at org.jenkinsci.plugins.gitclient.CliGitAPIImpl.access$200(CliGitAPIImpl.java:87)
    at org.jenkinsci.plugins.gitclient.CliGitAPIImpl$1.execute(CliGitAPIImpl.java:257)
    at org.jenkinsci.plugins.gitclient.RemoteGitImpl$CommandInvocationHandler$1.call(RemoteGitImpl.java:153)
    at org.jenkinsci.plugins.gitclient.RemoteGitImpl$CommandInvocationHandler$1.call(RemoteGitImpl.java:146)
    at hudson.remoting.UserRequest.perform(UserRequest.java:118)
    at hudson.remoting.UserRequest.perform(UserRequest.java:48)
    at hudson.remoting.Request$2.run(Request.java:328)
    at hudson.remoting.InterceptingExecutorService$1.call(InterceptingExecutorService.java:72)
    at java.util.concurrent.FutureTask.run(Unknown Source)
    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(Unknown Source)
    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(Unknown Source)
    at hudson.remoting.Engine$1$1.run(Engine.java:63)
    at java.lang.Thread.run(Unknown Source)
```

My understanding is that this should be a problem of the past, as the Git plugin in its current version shouldn't try to connect to Git via Java, only via the CLI client (which has no certificate issues). See [this thread](https://groups.google.com/forum/#!topic/jenkinsci-users/A-rn33CAEsM) for reference. However, the error does occur... How can I let my Jenkins slave connect to Git despite the self signed certificate?

Comment: This question appears to belong on another site in the Stack Exchange network because its not about programming. Perhaps [Super User](https://www.superuser.com/) or [Server Fault](http://serverfault.com/).

Comment: @jww For better or worse, tools primarily used for programming are on topic at SO, and both Git and Jenkins qualify.

Comment: @aknuds1 - I thought so too until [Coverity Scan Setup? - Closed](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/17766027/coverity-scan-setup).

Comment: @jww Well, questions about CI (e.g. Jenkins) and Git etc. are very common on SO, so I certainly hope it's not considered off-topic. Case in point, even the [help center](http://stackoverflow.com/help/on-topic) states that tools for programmers are on topic!

Comment: @jww, I think you were unlucky with your Coverty Scan question. I'd consider it on-topic (and I've just voted to re-open).

Answer (score 1):

This can be done by adding the self-signed certificate to the right place in the GIT config on the agent.

> http.sslCAInfo

Is the config option that you want, once you have found where this is using the following command on the agent you are ready to get the certificates.

```
git congif -list
```

This can be done using chrome or firefox, navigate to the site and get you self-signed certificate. using step details [here](https://superuser.com/questions/97201/how-to-save-a-remote-server-ssl-certificate-locally-as-a-file) they will need to be in PEM format.

Once you have the whole chain it can be added to the file that you found under  http.sslCAInfo. Please take a copy so that if you make a mistake you can roll it back to the previous set of certificates. Make sure to copy from the

```
--------------- BEGIN -----------
to 
--------------- END -------------
```

Once this is done the GIT will know to trust your self-certificated file.

**THIS IS NOT RECOMMENDED**

Optionally you can disable ssl verification on the agent using the option:

```
http.sslVerify
    Whether to verify the SSL certificate when fetching or pushing over HTTPS.
    Can be overridden by the GIT_SSL_NO_VERIFY environment variable.
```

**THIS IS NOT RECOMMENDED**